# Extract text from a document using notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a text file that I need to extract specific data elements from.

Example text:

> HI*ABK>Z48812~HI*APR>Z48812~HI*ABF>I2510*ABF>K810*ABF>I10*ABF>J449*ABF>F329*ABF>F419*ABF>I252~NM1*71*1*Darbinian*Sevak****XX*1306859178~LX*1~SV2*0551*HC>G0154*250*UN*4~DTP*472*D8*20180202~REF*6R*74990814~HL*3*1*22*0~HI*ABK>N390~HI*APR>N390~HI*ABF>B9620*ABF>B961*ABF>N319*ABF>G8220*ABF>S12300S*ABF>G9520*ABF>Z1612~NM1*71*1*Boonyaputthikul*Robert****XX*1700198801~LX*1~SV2*0551*HC>G0154*250*UN*4~DTP*472*D8*20180125~REF*6R*74990810~

I want to extract:

> Darbinian Sevak 1306859178
>
> Boonyaputthikul Robert 1700198801

How can do this with notepad++?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! What have you tried so far? Is your data formatted *exactly* as you have it above- one continuous line?

Comment: You can use regex or you can use any programming language to do it.

Comment: Yes one continuous line and I can seem to get the expression correct in regex

Comment: What are the rules used for extraction?

Comment: I'm not certain what you mean by rules for extraction.  I have a text file and right now I literally do a ctrl F to find NM1*71*1*, then I copy and paste the text following till the ~ into another document by hand.  Problem is I can easily have over 1000 instances of NM1*71*1* in a document and I have 250 documents to go through.

Answer (score 4):

This can't be done in a single step with Notepad++, you could do:

**First step:**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:^|\G).+?NM1\*71\*1\*(.+?)\*{4}XX\*(\d+)`
- Replace with: `$1 $2\n`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:             : non capture group
  ^             : beginning of line
 |              : R
  \G            : position of last match
)               : end group
.+?             : 1 or more any character, not greedy
NM1\*71\*1\*    : literally "MN1*71*1*", asterisk have to be escaped
(.+?)           : group 1, 1 or more any character, not greedy
\*{4}XX\*       : 4 asterisks, XX, then 1 asterisk 
(\d+)           : group 2, 1 or more digit
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1      : content of group 1
        : a space
$2      : content of group 2
\n      : line feed, you could change it for the linebreak you need
```

**Result for given example:**

```
Darbinian*Sevak 1306859178
Boonyaputthikul*Robert 1700198801
LX*1~SV2*0551*HC>G0154*250*UN*4~DTP*472*D8*20180125~REF*6R*74990810~
```

**In a second step, you have to delete the last line.**

Comment: Thank you so tremendously much, I will not forget how to do this!  Works perfectly.

Comment: @Missy: You're welcome, glad it helps.

Comment: @Missy: Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, see: https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers